# How to type a function that takes an array of arrays as input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, types

I have a function `drawSnake` which is called as follows:

```js
 drawSnake(
[
 [0, 0],
 [0, 1],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 3],
 [0, 4],
]
);
```

How can I type the input for this function?

I have tried something like `Array<Array<[number, number]>>` but it doesn't seem to be right.

```js
function drawSnake(snake: ???) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: `Array<Array<[number, number]>>` -> `Array<[number, number]>` you have *one* array with pairs of numbers in it, not an array of such arrays.

Comment: oh yeahh! Thanks @VLAZ! that solves it

Comment: `[number, number][]` works as well

Comment: @VLAZ Go ahead and create an answer :)

Comment: @LarsFlieger, VLAZ is it okay if I create an answer to this? using your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @VLAZ and @thedude in the comments above, this can be solved in 2 ways:

#1:

```js
   Array<[number, number]>
```

#2:

```js
   [number, number][]
```

Answer (score 0):

as stated on comments (@VLAZ). You can do it like this

```
function drawSnake(snake: Array<[number, number]>) {
    ...
  }
```